# There is a csv table, Count the number of customers per day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

There is a csv table, which contains customer access records from December 1 to December 7, but customers may be repeated every day. The customer field is user_id, and the date field is datentime. I want to count the number of different customers every day. But on December 2, we want to delete users who are duplicates on December 1, and on December 3, we want to delete users who are duplicates on December 2 and December 1, and so on. How to write a python statement?

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\user1222.csv')

 
df['datentime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datentime'])
 
unique_customers_per_day = []
current_unique_customers = set()

for date in pd.date_range(start='2023-11-25', end='2023-12-04'):
     
    current_day_data = df[df['datentime'].dt.date == date.date()]

    # Filter DataFrame based on date range
    filtered_df = df[(df['datentime'].dt.date >= pd.to_datetime('2023-11-25').date()) & (
                df['datentime'].dt.date <= pd.to_datetime('2023-12-04').date())]

    # Group by date and calculate unique customers per day
    unique_customers_per_day = filtered_df.groupby(filtered_df['datentime'].dt.date)['user_id'].nunique().reset_index()

    # Rename columns
    unique_customers_per_day.columns = ['date', 'unique_customers_count']

    # Print the result
    print(unique_customers_per_day.to_string(index=False))
```

but the result is :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date, unique_customers_count]
```

Comment: Please share some sample data from your csv file that reproduces the problem. See [mre].

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the input dataset and the matching expected output.